# What's the meaning of 溜个号 in 我出去溜个号

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context, mandarin

Sitting in a class, one says: 你帮我盯着点 我出去**溜个号**
I'd like to know what 溜个号 really means
Or is it just "I sneak out"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means ***he wants to sneak out and have a rest or do something else instead of being here and doing what he is supposed to do now***. He doesn't want to be seen by supervisors and wants you to watch out for him.

Answer (score 2):

[溜号](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/2117660671843627387.html)

> :〈方〉指偷偷走开。东北方言。注意力不集中，偷偷走开。

> :〈regional slang〉"to sneak away". Northeastern dialect. Trouble concentrating, sneak away

溜个号 break up the verb 溜号 into verb and object components and treat 号 as a noun, thus enabling a measure word 个 be placed before 号

Example

**溜号**去看庙会 = **Slip away** to see the temple fair

**溜**(个)**号**去看庙会 = **Slip away** (for once) to see the temple fair

你[溜]了幾次[号] = 你[溜号]了幾次